# How to create a list from nested JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a JSON which looks like this :

```json
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-05-31T18:15:47.927+03:00",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_model_golfController": {
                "Mode": 0,
                "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
            },
            "description": "Stop Station"
        },
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-05-31T18:15:47.927+03:00",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_model_golfController": {
                "Mode": 0,
                "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":12,\"StationAddress\":27}]"
            },
            "description": "Stop Station"
        }
    ],
    "statistics": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pageSize": 5
    }
}
```

I have created following classes : -

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<operation> operations { get; set; }
}

public class operation
{
    public golfController com_model_golfController { get; set; }
}

public class golfController
{
    public int mode { get; set; }
    public string StopStationPayload { get; set; }
}
```

I've been trying different things but not able to get the desired result.
Is my approach to form the above classes correct? I'm new to c# and trying to implement it.

What I want to achieve is to create a list which will contain objects : -

```json
{
   "Mode": 0,
   "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
},
{
   "Mode": 0,
   "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":12,\"StationAddress\":27}]"
}
```

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: It is unclear that you only want to deserialize the json or you want to serialize back the deserialized objects. Which one do you want?

Comment: @PeterCsala I want to still access them in ```{
   "Mode": 0,
   "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
}``` format but inside a list if there's more than one object and still be able to access each object as a whole if needed.

Comment: Do you want something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IPyHD8?

Comment: @PeterCsala Not really. I don't want individual values. I Want them inside a list as it is as they are here : ```{ "Mode": 0,    "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]" }``` so that I can later loop through the list and pass them as an individual payload.

Comment: Then use `root.operations.Select(op=>o.pcom_model_golfController).ToList();` as melmi suggested.

Comment: @PeterCsala How can I access the value of the key ```status``` from the json?? Suppose there's only one json object.

Comment: Well that's a different question. With or without data model?

Comment: @PeterCsala I tried this and it worked : ```JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            Console.WriteLine(obj["operations"][0]["id"]);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this question is not about JSON. It's about linq.

After deserializing your JSON with whatever library you use, you can obtain your `golfController` objects using linq and then serialize them.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var controllers = root.operations.Select(o=>o.com_model_golfController).ToList()
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(controllers);
```

Comment: Intresting!! Can I also loop through result like : ```foreach(var item in result) { Console.WriteLine(item); }``` to iterate through n number of such objects one by one?? Because when I tried doing that I'm getting every character in a new line.

Comment: Yes you can `controllers.forEach( p => { Console.WriteLine(p.Mode);});`

Comment: @CyrilleConMorales getting the following error : ```'List<golfController>' does not contain a definition for 'forEach' and no accessible extension method 'forEach' accepting a first argument of type 'List<golfController>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)```